# Responsive images in jQuery Mobile Listview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am using the example of clásico listview with thumbnails present in the jquery mobile documentation. But if I upload images with different sizes , they are not suitable for resolution. How to solve this?

The code: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview/#&ui-state=dialog

Comment: Are your images square? If not, depending on the scaling mode used, it might crop them or distort them. If they're being distorted, you may need to modify the images so that they're square. Ideally, it'd be good to create images specifically for this that are exactly 80 x 80 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use CSS max-width and max-height

```
li.ui-li-has-thumb img {
    max-width: 80px;
    max-height: 80px; 
}
```

or you can force the size you want:

```
li.ui-li-has-thumb img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px; 
}
```

Comment: `max-height` and `max-width` could be the solution, so I voted this up despite the rest of the CSS. I don't really think this is a good solution though. If the Images are large, computations must be done so they will be vector scaled properly which takes load time on the Client Side. You should scale the Images on the Server so they are the same size as their output.

Comment: So if the image is larger, does it basically create a smaller "view-port" cropping the rest of the image if it's too big? It sounds like the framework scales the image from the documentation, but I'm not sure how it handles non-square images.